# onafterprint event only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, sweetalert2

I need to carry out my own procedure after calling up the print function of the browser. The problem is that it only runs it once.

What can I do to make the `onafterprint` event always run?

```js
window.onafterprint = function() {
  location.href = '{% url 'logout_' %}';
}

Swal.fire({
  title: 'Example',
  showDenyButton: true,
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
  confirmButtonColor: 'green',
  denyButtonText: 'No',
  cancelButtonText: 'Cancel'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    flPrint = true;
  } else if (result.isDenied) {
    flPrint = false;
  }

  if ((result.isConfirmed) || (result.isDenied)) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '{% url 'ajax-view' %}',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: "application/json",
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(r) {
        if (r.result) {
          if (flPrint) {
            window.print();
          } else {
            location.href = '{% url 'logout_' %}';
          }
        }
      },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: your question is not clear!

Comment: you change the location href, what do you expect?

Comment: @Alex My problem, however, is not with the location.href, but with the window.print () immediately above, which seems to be executed only the first time you try to print the page.

Comment: @alisaberimovahed My problem, however, is not with the location.href, but with the window.print () immediately above, which seems to be executed only the first time you try to print the page.

Comment: I solved the problem: I just used mediaQueryList and the afterprint() event works always.